# CustomValue Annotation Processing : How can i create a similar annotation of @Value

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I have just started using annotation processing and trying to inject the value on the field annotated with my annotation . Since yesterday I am facing this error message: Compilation failure

I have tried to research and fix but unable to avoid this error here is my `CustomValueProcessor.java` class and  my annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomValue {
    String value(); // This attribute will hold the property value
}
```

```
import com.google.auto.service.AutoService;
import report.configurations.PropertyLoader;
import javax.annotation.processing.*;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement;
import javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("report.annotations.CustomValue")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_17)
@AutoService(javax.annotation.processing.Processor.class)
public class CustomValueProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    private Messager messager;
    private final Map<String, String> PropMap = PropertyLoader.parsePropertiesFile();

    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        super.init(processingEnv);
        messager = processingEnv.getMessager();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (TypeElement annotation : annotations) {
            for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotation)) {
                if (element.getKind() == ElementKind.FIELD) {
                    CustomValue annotationValue = element.getAnnotation(CustomValue.class);
                    String newParaName = annotationValue.value().substring(2, annotationValue.value().length() - 1);
                    String propertyValue = PropMap.get(newParaName);
                    //messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, propertyValue);
                    VariableElement fieldElement = (VariableElement) element;
                    String fieldName = fieldElement.getSimpleName().toString();
                    //messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, fieldName);
                    // Get the class type from the TypeElement
                    TypeElement enclosingClass = (TypeElement) fieldElement.getEnclosingElement();
                    TypeMirror classType = enclosingClass.asType();
                    //messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, classType.toString());
                    // Assuming PdfService is in the same package as enclosingClass
                    Class<?> clazz = enclosingClass.getClass();
                    // Get the field
                    try {
                        Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
                        //messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR,field.toString());
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        // Set the value of the field
                        field.set(null, propertyValue);  // Pass an object instance instead of null if the field is non-static
                    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please suggest/advice what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR` is making your processor generate compilation errors.

Comment: Also, what you're doing is never going to work. You are trying to set the field value at *compile* time, you need to do it at *runtime*. That's not something an annotation processor can do.

Comment: @Jorn i use the messager just to know the content of  propertyValue ,and  when I want to execute I comment out the line

Answer (score 0):

#### Background:

As far as I understand you mean Spring Boot's `@Value` annotation and as far as I read from Spring Boot documentation the elements annotated with `@Value` are initialized with the `@Value`'s value at runtime. In this answer, I am also going to address this very limited subset of similar functionality of `@Value` for your custom annotation.

In the simple case that I am aware of, annotation processors in Java are not running along with the source code being processed, but instead run at compilation time. That is you cannot have access through the `Processor` to objects generated at the runtime of the code you annotate. This is the reason you can't access the annotated `Field` you want at processing time. Another issue is that you are attempting to get a `Field` of the implementing `Class` of a `TypeElement` at processing time, which (as far as I understand) is not what you intend to do. These are the reasons why you get that error. On the other hand, you have access to the source code (being processed) itself through the Java annotation processing API (via `javax.lang.model.element.Element`s, `javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror`s and all related interfaces).

According to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14943661/6746785):

> standard annotation processing API does *not* support direct modification of source code

So, in order to go by the standard API, you can generate *new* code which will make use of the values of a simple `CustomValue` annotation. This new code will need to be called somehow by your application in order to initialize the annotated fields with their values. For example in Spring Boot you need to call a method for the whole application to begin such as the code in the following snippet:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The control flow of this method takes care of creating and initializing data objects for you (at least as far as my abstract understanding of Spring Boot goes). In a (distantly) similar way and in order to keep things simple, let's create a `Processor` which will generate the required functionality, but it will be your application's responsibility to call this functionality.

#### Limited-solution outline:

You can separate your code in two projects: one for the annotation processor and the annotation itself, and another project with the client code of the annotation. The *client* project will depend on the *annotation processor*'s project.

#### Annotation processor project code:

The annotation itself can be as you declared it:

```
package annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) //This has to be RUNTIME since we need the value of each CustomValue to exist at runtime.
public @interface CustomValue {
    String value();
}
```

while the annotation processor needs changes and for the purpose of this answer is implemented as:

```
package annotations;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.Filer;
import javax.annotation.processing.Messager;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedSourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind;
import javax.lang.model.element.PackageElement;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement;
import javax.lang.model.util.Elements;
import javax.lang.model.util.Types;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;

@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("annotations.CustomValue")
public class CustomValueProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    
    private final Map<String, String> propMap = Collections.singletonMap("person.id", "undefined"); //PropertyLoader.parsePropertiesFile();
    private final Map<TypeElement, Map<VariableElement, String>> classToFieldToValueMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public boolean process(final Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
                           final RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        final Messager messager = processingEnv.getMessager();
        final Elements elementUtils = processingEnv.getElementUtils();
        final Types typeUtils = processingEnv.getTypeUtils();
        final Filer filer = processingEnv.getFiler();
        annotations.forEach(annotation -> {
            roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotation).forEach(element -> {
                /*Checking for "element.getKind() == ElementKind.FIELD" is not really neeeded here
                as the code currently stands, since the CustomValue only supports FIELDs according
                to its Target meta-annotation, but let's indeed make the check since in the future
                we may support more Targets...*/
                if (element.getKind() == ElementKind.FIELD) {
                    final VariableElement fieldElement = (VariableElement) element;
                    final CustomValue annotationElement = element.getAnnotation(CustomValue.class);
                    final String annotationElementValue = annotationElement.value().trim();
                    
                    //Check for proper field declared type (String):
                    if (!typeUtils.isSameType(element.asType(), elementUtils.getTypeElement("java.lang.String").asType()))
                        messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "CustomValue annotated fields must be of type String.", element);

                    //Check for the specified value's sanity according to some simple parsing rules:
                    else if (annotationElementValue.isEmpty() || annotationElementValue.startsWith("="))
                        messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Empty parameter identifier for CustomValue.", element);

                    else {
                        //Parse with simple rules:
                        final String[] param = annotationElementValue.split("=", 2);
                        final String paramID = param[0].trim(),
                                     paramDefaultValue = (param.length > 1)? param[1].trim(): "N/A";
                        
                        //Find value:
                        final String paramValue = propMap.getOrDefault(paramID, paramDefaultValue);
                        final Element enclosingElement = element.getEnclosingElement();

                        //Reject enum constants (or anything else that is not a class, such as records):
                        if (enclosingElement.getKind() != ElementKind.CLASS)
                            messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Only class fields can be annotated with CustomValue.", element);
                        else {
                            final TypeElement enclosingClass = (TypeElement) enclosingElement;
                            final PackageElement pkg = elementUtils.getPackageOf(enclosingClass);

                            //Safety belt against inner classes (because, for simplicity, the rest of the code inside 'else' does not support this):
                            if (!Objects.equals(pkg, enclosingClass.getEnclosingElement()))
                                messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Only fields declared in top level classes are supported for CustomValue.", element);
                            else
                                classToFieldToValueMap.computeIfAbsent(enclosingClass, key -> new LinkedHashMap<>()).put(fieldElement, paramValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        
        /*
        Write to output files once at the end (or at least this is the intended behaviour).
        Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4146080/6746785
        */
        if (roundEnv.processingOver()) { // && !roundEnv.errorRaised()) {
            classToFieldToValueMap.forEach((enclosingClass, fieldToValue) -> {
                final PackageElement pkg = elementUtils.getPackageOf(enclosingClass);
                final String enclosingClassSimpleName = enclosingClass.getSimpleName().toString();
                final String newClassQualifiedName = enclosingClass.getQualifiedName().toString() + "Utils",
                             newClassSimpleName =    enclosingClassSimpleName                     + "Utils";
                try {
                    final VariableElement[] originatingElements = fieldToValue.keySet().toArray(new VariableElement[fieldToValue.size()]);
                    try (final Writer src = filer.createSourceFile(newClassQualifiedName, originatingElements).openWriter()) { //Use inherited source code encoding.
                        final String pkgQualifiedName = pkg.getQualifiedName().toString();
                        if (!pkgQualifiedName.isEmpty())
                            src.write("package " + pkgQualifiedName + ";\n\n");
                        src.write("import annotations.CustomValue;\n" +
                                  "import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;\n" +
                                  "import java.lang.reflect.Field;\n\n" +
                                  "public class " + newClassSimpleName + " {\n\n" +
                                  "    private static Field findFirstAnnotatedDeclaredField(final Class<?> clazz,\n" +
                                  "                                                         final String name,\n" +
                                  "                                                         final Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass) {\n" +
                                  "        for (Class<?> cur = clazz; cur != null; cur = cur.getSuperclass()) {\n" +
                                  "            try {\n" +
                                  "                final Field field = cur.getDeclaredField(name);\n" +
                                  "                if (field.getAnnotationsByType(annotationClass).length > 0)\n" +
                                  "                    return field;\n" +
                                  "            }\n" +
                                  "            catch (final NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {\n" +
                                  "            }\n" +
                                  "        }\n" +
                                  "        return null;\n" +
                                  "    }\n\n" +
                                  "    private static void suppressedWriteField(final Object object,\n" +
                                  "                                             final Field field,\n" +
                                  "                                             final Object value) {\n" +
                                  "        if (field != null) {\n" +
                                  "            field.setAccessible(true);\n" +
                                  "            try {\n" +
                                  "                field.set(object, value);\n" +
                                  "            }\n" +
                                  "            catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {\n" +
                                  "            }\n" +
                                  "        }\n" +
                                  "    }\n\n" +
                                  "    private static void defaultSuppressedWriteField(final Object object,\n" +
                                  "                                                    final String name,\n" +
                                  "                                                    final String value) {\n" +
                                  "        suppressedWriteField(object, findFirstAnnotatedDeclaredField(" + enclosingClassSimpleName + ".class, name, CustomValue.class), value);\n" +
                                  "    }\n\n" +
                                  "    public static void setToDefaults(final " + enclosingClassSimpleName + " refTo" + enclosingClassSimpleName + ") {\n");
                        
                        //WARNING: f2v.getValue() MUST be escaped to be used as a String literal in the generated code, but for simplicity I assume here it is valid already!
                        for (final Map.Entry<VariableElement, String> f2v: fieldToValue.entrySet())
                            src.write("        defaultSuppressedWriteField(refTo" + enclosingClassSimpleName + ", \"" + f2v.getKey().getSimpleName() + "\", \"" + f2v.getValue() + "\");\n");
                        src.write("    }\n" +
                                  "}\n");
                    }
                }
                catch (final IOException ioe) {
                    messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, ioe.toString(), enclosingClass);
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            classToFieldToValueMap.clear();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

After performing sanity checks on each round, the processor maintains all annotated fields and their values in map `classToFieldToValueMap`, in order to generate the source code in the last round.

Note: I used Java SE version 8 (the code may not support modules if ported to 9+, as well as other stuff possibly). Do not forget to correct the `@SupportedSourceVersion` value *if needed*, in case you port the code to a newer version.

#### Client project code:

```
import annotations.CustomValue;

public class Person {
    
    @CustomValue("person.id")
    private String id;
    
    @CustomValue("person.name = Random Name")
    private String name;
    
    @CustomValue("person.surname = The Surname")
    private String surname;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", surname=" + surname + '}';
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Person p = new Person();
        System.out.println(p); //Prints null fields.
        PersonUtils.setToDefaults(p); //PersonUtils was generated by the processor in the same package as Person.
        System.out.println(p); //Prints fields with their values assigned by CustomValue.
    }
}
```

#### Alternative limited-solution (without `Processor`):

It should be noted that, in this simple scenario, we don't even need to implement annotation processing. We can use reflection directly at runtime, on its own. We can modify a little the code generated by the above `Processor` with a more generic version which accepts any object and by using reflection detects and assigns `CustomValue` values to the fields of the object (where applicable). In this case one can use the following code (along with the annotation itself) in the *client* project directly:

```
import annotations.CustomValue;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class CustomValueUtils {

    private static List<Field> findAllAnnotatedDeclaredFields(final Class<?> clazz,
                                                              final Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass) {
        final ArrayList<Field> annotatedFields = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Class<?> cur = clazz; cur != null; cur = cur.getSuperclass()) {
            try {
                for (final Field field: cur.getDeclaredFields())
                    if (field.getAnnotationsByType(annotationClass).length > 0)
                        annotatedFields.add(field);
            }
            catch (final SecurityException e) {
            }
        }
        annotatedFields.trimToSize();
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(annotatedFields);
    }

    private static void suppressedWriteField(final Object object,
                                             final Field field,
                                             final Object value) {
        if (field != null) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                field.set(object, value);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void setToDefaults(final Object object) {
        final Map<String, String> propMap = Collections.singletonMap("person.id", "undefined"); //PropertyLoader.parsePropertiesFile();
        findAllAnnotatedDeclaredFields(object.getClass(), CustomValue.class).forEach(field -> {
            final CustomValue customVal = field.getAnnotation(CustomValue.class);
            final String annotationElementValue = customVal.value().trim();
            
            //Check for the specified value's sanity according to some simple parsing rules:
            if (annotationElementValue.isEmpty() || annotationElementValue.startsWith("="))
                throw new IllegalStateException("Empty parameter identifier for CustomValue2.");
            
            //Parse with simple rules:
            final String[] param = annotationElementValue.split("=", 2);
            final String paramID = param[0].trim(),
                         paramDefaultValue = (param.length > 1)? param[1].trim(): "N/A";

            //Find and set value:
            final String paramValue = propMap.getOrDefault(paramID, paramDefaultValue);
            suppressedWriteField(object, field, paramValue);
        });
    }
}
```

and use it as:

```
import annotations.CustomValue;

public class Person {
    
    @CustomValue("person.id")
    private String id;
    
    @CustomValue("person.name = Random Name")
    private String name;
    
    @CustomValue("person.surname = The Surname")
    private String surname;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", surname=" + surname + '}';
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Person p = new Person();
        System.out.println(p);
        CustomValueUtils.setToDefaults(p); //Can be any Object, but is intended for objects with fields annotated with CustomValue.
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

Note in each solution I faked `PropertyLoader.parsePropertiesFile();` with `Collections.singletonMap("person.id", "undefined");` for simplicity.